# mysql true/false/ mc questions table

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql but I am trying to make a quiz website as a pet project in php and store questions and answers in mysql. I want to have multiple choice and true and false questions for now. What would be the best way to do this. Should I create one table or two for the types of question. Any tips on how to write this?

Comment: One tip is that the yes / no question is very much same as multiple choices question. There is multiple choices, first one is yes and second one is no...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to use one table.
I would say creating 2 tables will be good. Your question is light compare to what you intend to build. But if I guess right you will want to print result after submit... Then comes the answers table. If you are not using cookies, then "participant" should have a table too methinks.
Goodluck on your project it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose 3 tables.

1) Table with information about question and its type

2) Table for storing TF and question id

3) table for storing multiple choice options and question id

```
1) challenge_question table:
    id
    challenge_id
    question (text of the question)
    required (some questions will be required to be displayed per each challenge)
    question_type (here I indicate what type of question: Mult. choice, T/F)

2) challenge_question_mc (multiple choice)
    question_id = FK/PK to challenge_question
    option = text of the option
    is_correct = Boolean to indicate the answer

3) challenge_question_tf (true or false)
    question_id = FK/PK to challenge_question
    is_correct = Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both true/false and multiple choice questions (and don't want separate tables for each type of question) you could make the following three tables.

Question:

```
QuestionId: int unsigned primary key
Text: varchar
```

Answer:

```
AnswerId: int unsigned primary key
Text: varchar
```

QuestionAnswer:

```
QuestionId: int unsigned
AnswerId: int unsigned
IsCorrect: boolean
```

When you want to display the possible answers to a question you can `JOIN` the last two tables:

```
SELECT Answer.AnswerId, Answer.Text FROM Answer JOIN QuestionAnswer ON
Answer.AnswerId = QuestionAnswer.AnswerId WHERE QuestionId = ?
```

And if you want to check whether a given answer is correct you can use:

```
SELECT IsCorrect FROM QuestionAnswer WHERE QuestionId = ? AND AnswerId = ?
```

which will return 1 for the correct answer and 0 for wrong ones.

You can reuse rows in the Answer table if you don't want to create a new set of e.g. true/false answers for each question. Just make sure to connect questions with possible answers in the QuestionAnswer table and mark the combinations as true or false (1 = true, 0 = false).

If you don't care about reusing possible answers in different questions I guess it would suffice with two tables if you merged Answer and QuestionAnswer into a single table.

You might want some other tables later on if you want to separate the questions to specific quizzes. That could be achieved by making a Quiz table with QuizId and Name:

```
QuizId: int unsigned primary key
Name: varchar
```

and another table QuizQuestion where you tie QuizId and QuestionId together:

```
QuizId: int unsigned
QuestionId: int unsigned
```

Then you can use `JOIN` on the tables to get the questions of a specific quiz.